# jQuery offset on iframe

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jQuery offset to work on an iframe. I would like to get the position of a mouse click relative to the iframe where the user has clicked.

This code is working on an IMG, but not on an IFRAME:

```
// Not working
$('iframe').click(function(e)
{   
    var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

    var left = Math.round( (e.clientX - offset_l) );
    var top = Math.round( (e.clientY - offset_t) );

    alert("Left: " + left + " Top: " + top);

});
```

I've set up an code example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QR6kT/)

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Nope. Can't bind click events to iFrames, that is, unless, they're of the same origin.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe element does not allow events like click, but you can create a div over the iframe and apply the click function on it, for example:

```
<div class="container">
  <iframe width="500" height="200" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Add the style to "hide" events handler from iframe:

```
.container iframe{ pointer-events: none }
```

And then change click event from iframe to .container.

```
$('.container').click(function(e)
{   
    var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

    var left = Math.round( (e.clientX - offset_l) );
    var top = Math.round( (e.clientY - offset_t) );

    alert("Left: " + left + " Top: " + top);
});
```

Problem? The iframe will not be accessible, but you could manage it (adding and removing pointer-events style from iframe) with Javascript.

**Update**:

I add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KbYt/) to explain better the answer (with control button to "enable" or "disable" iframe).

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you please update the answer on how to use pointer events to make the iframe clickable?

Comment: Sorry Rasmus, iframe cannot use events. You can only put a transparent div over iframe and click it to "simulate" that you are clicking iframe. I made a example using a control button to activate/deactivate iframe, maybe is that you needs. Take a look to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KbYt/) ;)